How to login a firebase user from a kotlin/JavaScript (not Android/web)
tl/dr;
How do I login a (test) Firebase user and retrieve their JWT (to call a 3rd service) from within a kotlin/JavaScript that's NOT an android app / web page?
Context:
I have an existing Firebase setup, an app, and backend. I'm trying to write a kotlin script (a gatling loadtest of our backend).
To test our backend from the script I can easily create users in Firebase (to mimic normal user signups from the app)
val userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUser(
            UserRecord.CreateRequest()
                .setUid(test_uid)
                .setDisplayName(test_displayName)
                .setEmail(test_email)
                .setPassword(test_password)
                .setEmailVerified(true))

But then I need to log that user in and get hold of the JWT Firebase would create for the  account so I can then make authenticated calls to our server api.  But all the docs on this assume one is in an Android app, e.g. things like
auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {

but signInWithEmailAndPassword, nor anything like it, seems to be available in the firebase-admin maven package - and the firebase-auth package doesn't seem to play well with maven (is it app only? It's not mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup ...)
So is this possible from a non-app jvm program? Has anyone done this? Any clues gratefully received...

The com.google.firebase:firebase-auth artifact is for Android apps only. It won't be of use to you for this task.
What you can do is use the Admin SDK to create a custom token for the user's UID, which would normally provide to the client to sign in.  But instead of signing in on the client, you can just turn around and provide that token directly to your backend for verification.
It's up to you to make sure the custom token has all the same properties that you would expect from the token that comes from signing in normally.

Thanks Doug, I did try that, but I got an error in my backend FirebaseAuthException: verifyIdToken() expects an ID token, but was given a custom token – I presume I need to use .createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)  but how do I find out which claims in the token are necessary?

Custom claims are entirely your decision for your app's special needs.  If you didn't grant any before, then you don't need to grant any now.

Right. The normal app code is not adding any custom claims - so why is Firebase backend integration complaining FirebaseAuthException: verifyIdToken() expects an ID token, but was given a custom token? How do I use FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid); to produce a proper ID token?

Look into the Firebase Auth REST API to see what the SDK does behind the scenes. Specifically: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-verify-custom-token

For completeness - In fact, in this case, I just logged-in the users direct with Sign in with email / password  - with the API key found in the firebase console
Sucks that this isn't included as part of the firebase-admin client library though :-(
